# In Azure Devops every-time we run a pipeline does it create a new commit or what exactly happens...?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-repo

As I run a pipeline, it showed me this point

[commit ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqywN.png)

How does this actually work? And is the the status update on existing source code commit or a new commit saved all the config of the running pipeline?

I tried to look at the MS docs but it wasn't clear for me.

Comment: It's the commit of the code that has been downloaded from the repo. Go compare that commit id to the actual repo that feeds the pipeline and you'll see they are the same

Answer (score 1):

No. A pipeline run doesn't create a new commit. A commit comes from the repository. So anytime you restart the same pipeline it will use the same commit id unless there is a change on the repository.

Comment: yeah your right, i reverified Thank you!